# Attempting to reference a deleted function with vector of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, vector, polymorphism, unique-ptr

I'm trying to make a text-based Monopoly game. For each tile on the board, I have a Tile or PropertyTile object. PropertyTile is a child of the Tile class, with extra properties.
Originally I had a vector to hold all the tiles, both Tile and PropertyTile, but later found out that because of Object slicing, the correct way would be to use unique_ptr.

As I switched over to unique_ptr, I got 2 of the same error:

```
Error   C2280    'std::unique_ptr<Tile,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::operator =(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
    with
    [
        _Ty=Tile
    ]   MonopolyFinal   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\include\xutility    1768
```

The first one was solved by putting move() in Map::getAllTiles(), as shown below.
The second error is pointing to line 30 of Map.h, which is (`vector<unique_ptr<Tile>> tiles;`).

For Map.cpp Map::Map(), I tried both emplace_back and push_back, with and without move().

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. All relevant code below. Thanks in advance.

Map.h:

```
    class Map
{
    public:

        Map();

        void display(Player, Player, Player, Player);

        vector<unique_ptr<Tile>> getAllTiles();

        vector<vector<bool>> getAllTileValidty();

    private:
        vector<unique_ptr<Tile>> tiles;
        vector<vector<bool>> tileValidity;
    };
```

Constructor in Map.cpp that populates the tiles vector:

```
Map::tiles.push_back(move(unique_ptr<Tile>(new PropertyTile("Mediterranean Ave", 9, 10, "Brown", 60, 2, 50) )));
Map::tiles.push_back(move(unique_ptr<Tile>(new Tile("Community Chest", 8, 10)))); //Community Chest (usually gives you extra money)
```

The getter for the tiles vector:

```
    vector<unique_ptr<Tile>> Map::getAllTiles()
{
    return move(tiles);
}
```

Comment: Your code you have posted looks fine (result-wise). It is likely the issue is elsewhere. Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Errors are not reproducible based on provided code. 
Improve with  Map::tiles.emplace_back(std::make_unique<PropertyTile>(params...));

Comment: Is getAllTiles supposed to return a copy, or do you just want to access the "tiles" variable that is stored in Map? In the latter case, you should just return a const vector<...>&".

Answer (score 1):

The root of your problems is that `std::unique_ptr` can't be copied, only moved. It can't be copied, since only one `unique_ptr` can own the object. All your errors are due to cases where you try to copy such `unique_ptr` objects, despite that. Of course, you can replace `std::unique_ptr`, with `std::shared_ptr`, but then the same object will be shared across several Map objects. Modify the pointed object from one `Map` and it affects the other. Not sure you want that.

Most likely, your move solution is wrong:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Tile>> Map::getAllTiles()
{
    return move(tiles);
}
```

This will destroy the `tiles` in the `Map` object. Either the name of the function is wrong, or that is not what you want. A likely solution would be to use `clone()`

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Tile>> Map::getAllTiles()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Tile>> result;
    result.reserve(tiles.size());
    for (const auto & tile_ptr: tiles) 
    {
        result.push_back(tile_ptr->clone());
    }  
    return result; // OK, a local is automatically moved, possibly elided 
}
```

Where Tile, and all its descendants, implement clone:

```
class Tile {
  ...
  virtual std::unique_ptr<Tile> clone() const 
  { 
     return std::make_unique<Tile>(*this);
  }
  ..
};
class PropertyTile : public Tile {
  ...
  std::unique_ptr<Tile> clone() const override
  { 
     return std::make_unique<PropertyTile>(*this);
  }
  ..
};
```

As for the error at line 30 of Map.h, which is `(vector<unique_ptr<Tile>> tiles;)`, I suspect this is due to an auto-generated copy constructor. Either delete copy and assignment:

```
class Map {
 public:
    Map(const Map&) = delete;
    Map& operator=(const Map&) = delete;
```

Either that, or implement them properly by cloning all the elements of the vector, one by one.

Also, even though not the root of your problem, the following is far from best practice:

```
push_back(move(unique_ptr<Tile>(new PropertyTile(....
```

Better use `std::make_unique`, which is available since C++14:

```
push_back(std::make_unique<PropertyTile>("Mediterranean Ave", 9, 10,....
```

Lastly, never write `using namespace std` anywhere in your code, nor `using std::vector` in the header file. Both are wrong:

- `using namespace std` is a nightmere for keeping the code forward-compatible for newer versions of the C++ standard.
- `using std::vector` is a nightmare for the users of `Map.h` that might want to use a different header file that has a different vector type, such as `using std::pmr::vector`. These will clash each other.

**Update**:
c++ ranges can be used to simplify some code. Assuming C++23, it is possible to rewrite things:

```cpp
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Tile>> Map::getAllTiles()
{
    return std::ranges::transform(tiles, 
                                  [](const auto & ptr) { return ptr->clone(); })
        | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();
}
```